# What does Kurome say in AkaKill Theater Ep. 22?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I was watching the *Akame ga Kill* ONAs, and in *AkaKill Theater* episode 22, Kurome is constantly pointing out that Akame doesn't get enough air-time even though the series is named after her and talking smack to her.

She then says something starting with `Ba-`, and is immediately censored. The dialogue goes something like this:

> ***Run:*** We're just about out of time, so let's at least have a good-
>
> ***Kurome:*** Sis. Ba-  * censored *
>
> *Everyone is stunned, the display in the back says  **"She actually said it!"***
>
> ***Run:*** So I think, that's enough for today
>
> ***Akame:** (Super Pissed)* Kurome, meet me outside

[image: Kurome, censored]
[image: Akame is pissed]

So what does she say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://nozomi.2ch.sc/test/read.cgi/ymag/1417014469/669), Kurome most likely said something along the lines of "Sis, you are just like Bakabon" or "Sis, have you heard of Bakabon?" given the context.

> 以前このスレで妹を斬るの回のアカ斬る劇場でアカメとクロメが話してて
>   クロメが最後に何て言ってたのか？って話題があったが　**あれは多分
>   「お姉ちゃん　バカボンみたいだね」か「お姉ちゃんバカボンって知ってる？」
>   のどちらかだと思う。**

[Tensai Bakabon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensai_Bakabon) is another show named after someone who, like Akame, [didn't have anywhere near enough screen time for a title character](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/what-does-akame-ga-kill-mean-and-why-is-it-called-that), as it is

> Bakabon's troublemaker father who eventually steals the show and becomes the central character.

So essentially, Kurome is just mocking Akame for the fact that she was upstaged by a supporting character (Kurome herself), **for the third time**.